# Puma web server (ROR) and connection timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, puma

i have a custom setup of Ruby on rails and using puma as a web server (backed by Nginx - socket)

The database I am connection to is a rds medium (so 296 connections limit). My puma setup is threads 1:32 and 4 workers. With a connection pool of 128.

I have a high load 300 requests/sec and every lets say 1000 requests a longer calculation is made that takes about 3 seconds (getting all the events, making some calculations and updating them).

I am getting the error

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError: could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.016 seconds)
```

But if I look at the rds database only 43 connections are opened. My memory is like 2000 MB out of 7000 MB (the 2 core processors are at 100%) I am wondering why do I get a connection timeout even if all my connections are not opened (and of course is the puma configuration ok)?

Thank for your help!

EDIT:

In my puma.rb I have:

```
on_worker_boot do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect!

  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
    config = Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
    config['reaping_frequency'] = ENV['DB_REAP_FREQ'] || 10 # seconds
    config['pool']              = ENV['DB_POOL'] || 128
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
end
```

Comment: check your database pool settings in `database.yml`

Comment: No pool settings just adapter, encoding, host, port, username, password, database, su_password, su_username.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a default value or if nil = unlimited

Comment: The default size is 5, but I have added my puma.rb config for the 128 pool size.

Comment: ok, well does the `ENV['DB_POOL']` contain a number ?

Comment: well i have no idea then, guess you'll need to wait for another person to answer

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here in the [rails configuration guide about database pooling](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling), when all the db connections are exhausted, ActiveRecord will wait for one to free up, I assume the number you increased is the http connection limit, not the db connection limit,
You could edit your `database.yml` and increase you connection limit to say `296` which is the limit of the rds instance

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: /path/to/sock
  pool: 296
  # username, password, etc
```

Comment: I have edited my post with the setting inside the puma.rb. Does not this count as the pool inside the database.yml?